# Ember deleting objects using em methods

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Hai once again ive deleting action to take care of.

Ive array and parameter with given item to be removed

**[
Class
, 
Class
, 
Class
, 
Object**>

> __ember1393425759417_meta: Meta
>
> formId: 4
>
> **proto**: Object

Where classes are existing records in the database, i can delete them and it works (else block). PS! Parameter is the exact same object / class that needs to be deleted

```
deleteFieldset: function(formID){
      if(this.get('controller').get('isEditController')){
        //Checks if edit controller

        var allPersonArray = this.get('controller').content._data.persons;
        if(allPersonArray[formID.formId -1] !== undefined){
                                    //TODO:    Delete generated objects
        }else{
          formID.destroyRecord();  // Deleting records works.
        }
      }else{}
```

I tried removeAt, removeObject, but no luck.

Given output with removeAt on the newly generated object in the array.

> TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method
>   'inverseFor'

On the other hand i cant splice em either, cus that does not affect hbs...

Comment: `inverseFor` is from Ember-Data, so it seems like that array should be an array of models. But you have an `Object` at the end, which is not a subclass of `Model`. I'm not really surprised that it's failing on you. How did that object even get into that array?

Comment: @GJK Doing dynamic form editing, models in array are existing records and the objects r newly created items . http://dpaste.com/1665038/

Comment: @GJK How else would i add new forms to edit template ???? Creating new empty record doesnt work since, the table has 2 primary keys. Table has STUDY_ID ; PERSON_ID and ROLL(string).. So i print on hbs {{each person}} gives me amount of persons from API, and inside it there's a form .. Now i ad another it adds and object to model array

Comment: And then i end up with this class, class,class, object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having trouble creating records, so I'll try to explain. First, in the latest versions of Ember-Data, the store is supposed to create new records for you. Example:

```
var record = this.get('store').createRecord({
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2' 
});

record.set('belongsToRelationship', otherRecord);
record.set('hasManyRelationship', new Em.Set());

records.save();
```

This will create a proper record for you, and when you call `.save()` on that record, the adapter will persist it to the server for you.

As far as primary keys go, you can't create those on the client side. Whatever you think might be working right now by just incrementing the last primary key, will **not** work when you have more than one client. (Hell, it probably won't even work now.) Your server is supposed to create the primary keys. You create a record, like I did above. When you save it to the server, your server should respond with a payload that includes the saved record, primary keys included. Ember-Data will then load that payload into the record you just created, populating the primary key fields.

Comment: I was using given approach. As another form is added i pushObject to personArray, Which is printed out using {{each personArray}} Then client fills out fields and presses "Edit". Now i checked if PersonArray[i].id existed or not, if it did, i simply saved, if not I made createRecord('person',hash).save();  But now as i see i need to have an ModelArray in order to delete, i tried to save an empty record. API respsonse was "person&study" cant be empty... Person is belongsTo and so is study. Meaning i have to give   some empty Modelobject for both of them , or record will not be created.

Comment: http://www.pardot.com/wp-content/help/uploads/2010/10/Screen-Shot-2013-01-14-at-2.29.03-PM.png Form looks something like this. Fields : Person / Role (Hidden - study)

Comment: You don't have to save a record as soon as you create. As I've done above, I created it, worked with it a bit, then saved it. Also, you can set a `belongsTo` relationship to `null` if you don't have the values when you create the record.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/1669261/ .. Btw is creating record to store not async ? I mean i couldnt use promise on it .    query.then(fun1, fun2) said objectobject does not have function then .